# Relation between a continued fraction and partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions, continued-fractions

I am interested in the continued fraction
$$\sum\limits_k {{z^{{2^k} - 1}}}  = \frac{1}{{1 - \frac{{{T_0}z}}{{1 - \frac{{{T_1}z}}{{1 - \frac{{{T_2}z}}{{1 -{ \ddots }}}}}}}}}.$$

OEIS  [A104977](http://oeis.org/A104977) states  without proof that   ${T_k} = {( - 1)^{b(k + 2) + 1}}$ (see [A090678](http://oeis.org/A090678)) if $b(n)$ denotes the number of non-squashing partitions of $n$  into distinct parts (see [A088567](http://oeis.org/A088567)).

I obtained the sequence ${T_k}$ with another method which has nothing to do with partitions,  but I would be interested to learn why there is a connection with those partitions. Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: Let me give some more information about the sequence $T_n.$
Let  $$D(n) = \det \left( {{a_{i + j}}} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1}$$ be a Hankel determinant of the sequence $(a_n), $ where $a_n=1$ if $n+2$ is a power of $2$ and $a_n=0$ else.

Then $$ T_n=D(n)D(n+2).$$ These numbers satisfy $T_{2n}=T_{2n-1}T_{n-1}$ and $T_{2n+1}=-T_{2n}$with initial values $T_0=1$ and $T_1=-1.$

The non-squashing partitions with distinct parts $b(n)$ satisfy $b(2n)=b(2n-1)+b(n)-1$ and $b(2n+1)=b(2n)+1.$

Thus a posteriori it can be observed that $${T_k} = {( - 1)^{b(k + 2) + 1}}.$$
**Question**: Is this a happy coincidence or is there really a connection between the Hankel determinants and the partitions.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A090678 links to two papers on "non-squashing partitions". Was there nothing useful at those links?

Comment: [A088567](http://oeis.org/A088567)  gives more links.

Comment: Since $z^{2^k-1}=z^{2^0}z^{2^1}\dots z^{2^{k-1}}$, there is another immediate continued fraction given by the Euler continued fraction formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_original_formula

Comment: @Pietro Majer: Thank you for this information. But I am only interested in this specific continued fraction which is related to the Hankel determinants of the sequence $(a_n),$ where $a_n=1$ if $n+2$ is a power of $2$ and $a_n=0$ else.

Comment: @Gerry Myersaon and Alexey Ustinov: I have looked at these links but have not seen any real connection with non-squashing partitions. The only connection seems to be that the non-squashing partitions modulo $2$ give the same values as $T_n.$  What I really want to know: Is this a lucky chance because they obey the same recursions or is there a proof where these partitions play an essential role?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Sorry for the typo in your name. But the website has not allowed me to edit my comment.

Comment: I am no expert, but there should be some works of Flajolet about combinatorial interpretations for continued fractions. In general, Henkel determinants, continued fractions and orthogonal polynomials are precisely related to each other and in turn they are related (e.g. via the Gessel-Lindstrom-Viennot lemma) to combinatorics, more precisely to weighted Motzkin paths. Sometimes Motzkin paths are related to partitions (see Mansour-Shattuck work), but I don't know enough. By the way I think that the interpretation of non-squashing partitions as binary partitions suits better the problem here.